# Prevent flexbox display in a new line

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent and two main children. The first child has two elements with fixed width and height. The second child has some text and when I resize text is shown or hidden in response to page size. But when I resize at a certain point the two elements of the first child insted of staying inline they go one above the other. How can I prevent this?

[image: So in the second image the two elements are one above other and I don't want this.]

So in the second image the two elements are one above other and I don't want this.

fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXMz7/406/)

html

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="icon-div">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
  <div class="text-div">This is text I'd like to truncate when space doesn't permit</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent-div {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.text-div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: hidden;    
    min-width: 0;
}

.icon-div {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.icon-div div {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't let your `.icon-div` shrink (`flex: 1 0 auto`);

```
.icon-div {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Setting: `white-space:nowrap` has the unfortunate side effect of having the text in `text-div` run into the space occupied by `icon-div` when the screen becomes too small.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `icon-div` class:

```
.icon-div {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```